# How to use lambda response in AWS?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, zip

I have written a lambda function that reads a file (called key) from an s3 bucket and should return it to the UI as a response.

I am kind of stuck on how to get this working:

My code so far:

```py
key = event['name']
#s3.download_file(bucketName, key, key)
file = s3.get_object(Bucket = bucketName, Key = key)
f = file['Body'].read()
return {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "isBase64Encoded": 'true',
    "Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename=" + key,
    "Content-Encoding": "zip",
    "headers": {"Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"},
    "body":  f
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution for this:
[s3-pre-signed-url-guide](https://www.cloudberrylab.com/resources/blog/s3-pre-signed-url-guide/)

Create a pre signed url via the api.

```
url = s3.generate_presigned_url(
            ClientMethod='get_object',
            Params={
                'Bucket': bucketName,
                'Key': key
            }
        )
        logger.info('url: %s', url)
        return {
            "statusCode": 200,
            "body":  url
            }
```